# Emotion Detection in Text: Can't open hdf5 and incorrect classification report?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, h5py

I'm trying to follow along this code for the emotion detection SemEval task from a few years ago.

While I'm running the whole thing on spyder, I'm getting two main errors which I've attempted at fixing using this community's advice but still, my classification report is NOT what the author of this code got.

Please see this original Code: https://github.com/sismetanin/emosense-semeval2019-task3-emocontext/blob/master/EmoSense%20at%20SemEval2019%20Task%203%20EmoContext.ipynb

**Problem 1** [line 29]:
`model.load_weights("models/bidirectional_LSTM_best_weights_0010-0.9125.hdf5")`

Error:
`OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'models/bidirectional_LSTM_best_weights_{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.4f}.hdf5', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)`

**Problem 2** [line 25]:

```
filepath = "models/bidirectional_LSTM_best_weights_{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.4f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False,
                             mode='auto', save_freq=1)
tensorboardCallback = TensorBoard(log_dir='./Graph', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)

history = model.fit([message_first_message_train, message_second_message_train, message_third_message_train],
                    np.array(labels_categorical_train),
                    callbacks=[metrics_callback, checkpoint, tensorboardCallback],
                    validation_data=(
                        [message_first_message_val, message_second_message_val, message_third_message_val],
                        np.array(labels_categorical_val)
                    ),
                    epochs=20,
                    batch_size=200)
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'Failed to format this callback filepath: "models/bidirectional_LSTM_best_weights_{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.4f}.hdf5". Reason: \'val_acc\''
```

For this, I've tried 'val_accuracy' as suggested by some other forums in the `filepath` and `checkpoint` lines but the same error occurs.

**Problem 3**:
My classification report is:

```
f1_e 0.049438202247191004
precision_e 0.39285714285714285
recoll_e 0.026378896882494004
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.85      0.99      0.92      2338
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00       142
           2       0.67      0.06      0.12       125
           3       0.19      0.02      0.04       150

    accuracy                           0.85      2755
   macro avg       0.43      0.27      0.27      2755
weighted avg       0.76      0.85      0.79      2755
```

It is entirely different from the original code's report which is below:

```
f1_e 0.7313432835820894
precision_e 0.6583493282149712
recoll_e 0.8225419664268585
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.97      0.93      0.95      2338
           1       0.64      0.76      0.69       142
           2       0.70      0.84      0.76       125
           3       0.65      0.87      0.74       150

   micro avg       0.91      0.91      0.91      2755
   macro avg       0.74      0.85      0.79      2755
weighted avg       0.92      0.91      0.92      2755
```

Why doesn't mine show 'micro avg' (instead it shows accuracy)? Could problem 1 and 2 be the reason why my report is very different from theirs?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello! Please post your code as part of your question, because linking to other sites makes it hard to follow up and solve. Copy-paste works just fine for these situations.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please limit each post to 1 question/error (per Stackoverflow guidelines).

The first 2 error messages have to do with declaration/evaluation of `filepath`:

```
filepath = "models/bidirectional_LSTM_best_weights_{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.4f}.hdf5"
```

**UPDATE**
I should have read the Keras documentation before writing my answer. :-) It explains the most likely cause of problems 1 and 2. Ref here: [Keras ModelCheckpoint docs](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/). For the `filepath` argument it says (in part):

***filepath** can contain named formatting options, which will be filled the value of epoch and keys in logs (passed in on_epoch_end). For example: if filepath is* `weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5`, *then the model checkpoints will be saved with the epoch number and the validation loss in the filename*. Note that it uses `val_loss` and not `val_acc`. This could also explain your question under Problem 3.

This looks like a Python "f-string" format (but without the leading `f`), where variables enclosed in `{ }` are evaluated to create the string. The `filepath` string is passed to `ModelCheckpoint`, which needs values for `epoch` and `val_acc` to complete the evaluation. `ModelCheckpoint` is imported from `keras.callbacks`. I am not familiar with that function, so can't help. Have you read the Keras docs for that function?

I can't comment on `val_acc` vs `val_accuracy`. I suspect it's a reserved Keras keyword/variable. Again, do Keras docs mention this?

Regarding Problem 3 -- I'm curious, how did you get the classification report after these errors? Are you running with the same Keras version as the author? This work is almost 3 years old (last commit Feb 28, 2019). It's entirely possible the differences are due to results from different versions.